# Data Annonation Custom Attribut [DateTime]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm trying to add Data Validation To my DateTime Attribut i want to oblige user to select Date between `DateTime.Now` and smaller then one years after `DateTime.now.addyears(+1)`
This is my code :

```
 public class DateDebut : ValidationAttribute
        {
            public override bool IsValid(object value)
            {
                if (value == null) return false;
                DateTime enteredDate = (DateTime)value;

                if ( (enteredDate >= DateTime.Now) && (enteredDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(+1)))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "De : ")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DateDebut(ErrorMessage="Date invalide")]
        public DateTime dd { get; set; }
```

This Custom Validation dosn't work, verification is not excuted, ai think i'm missed something realy simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree completelt with Daniel,

However I find that when i am needing to do comparisons of properties in my model I use the IValidatableObject

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx

I find it faster and easier for most small types of comparisons
you would have some that looks like this

```
public class myModel : IvalidatableObject
{
 string debut = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
 string fin = DateTime.Now.AddYears(+1).ToShortDateString(); 
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "De : ")]
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 public DateTime dd { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate()
  {
    if(this.debut > this.fin)
    {
      yield return new ValidationResult("debut cannot be greated then fin");
    }
  }
}
```

read up and see whats best for you

Comment: There is no reason this wouldnt work.
post your code for your controller action. and the code for your view as well

Comment: it work's i forgot to add some other parametre , but i wondering how how to enable this validation at client side, i have activated the client side validation it work for other form, but not in this one.

Comment: You would need to write custom Javasscript that would perform the equivalent client side validation. The reason it works on client side for other validation is because you included the unobtrusive library that Microsoft includes

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are static in nature. Have you considered writing your own attribute for validation? There are several examples on the web that should get you started.

You could also inherit from `RangeAttribute` and inject it as needed.